# What AWS Role Policies do I need to be able to run AWS CLI commands

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, aws-device-farm, aws-policies, aws-roles

When ever I run a command to get DeviceFarm projects or Schedule a run I get errors stating that I do not have permissions to run the commands and that there is an explicit deny on my user.

I am in the role settings and cannot find any policy to add to enable me to run these commands.

What policy do I need to add?

The command: `aws devicefarm schedule-run <options>`

The error: `User: arn:<user arn> is not authorized to perform: devicefarm:ScheduleRun on resource: <resource arn> with an explicit deny`

Comment: Please Edit your question to show the commands that are failing and the _exact_ error message.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I've added requested details

Comment: Normally, I would say that you could add the `AWSDeviceFarmFullAccess` policy on your IAM User, but the **explicit** deny suggests that something is intentionally prohibiting such access. Are you using an AWS Account that is part of an AWS Organizations hierarchy? If so, it is possible that a [Service control policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/organizations/latest/userguide/orgs_manage_policies_scps.html) is blocking use of the Device Farm service in the account.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I already have AWSDeviceFarmFullAccess listed on my role. And yes, device farm as part of a bigger aws suite of stuff.

Comment: If your account is a sub-account within AWS Organizations, please talk with your company's AWS administrators to check whether any SCPs are blocking your use of Device Farm.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein will do and let you know

Comment: @JohnRotenstein is there a way to specify what role to use as part of the command?

Comment: An IAM Role needs to be 'assumed' rather than 'passed' to a command. If you have permission to assume a role, you can add it to the AWS CLI configuration file and it will assume the role for you. See: [Using an IAM role in the AWS CLI - AWS Command Line Interface](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-role.html)

Comment: @JohnRotenstein can you add the details about "adding devicefarm policy and something else causing my issue" as an answer so I can mark it as correct please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, I would say that you could add the `AWSDeviceFarmFullAccess` policy on your IAM User, but the **explicit deny** suggests that something is intentionally prohibiting such access.

If you are using an AWS Account that is part of an AWS Organizations hierarchy, it is possible that a [Service control policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/organizations/latest/userguide/orgs_manage_policies_scps.html) is blocking use of the Device Farm service in the account.

Answer (score 0):

Precede your commands with sudo. That will enable you to run the commands with an elevated privilege and you should not encounter some of the challenges you are encountering.

Comment: would it be `sudo aws command subcommand` or would it be `aws sudo command subcommand` ?

Comment: This answer is not applicable to the AWS CLI.

Comment: Sudo did nothing, the permissions issue is on AWS and not local

Comment: I answered before you had added the commands that were failing. Now there is a bit more clarity and it seems like an AWS  Security Policy issue.

Comment: makes sense charles